# General error: 1843 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01843: not a valid month (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)'

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I am trying to insert to a oracle table using pdo. Its getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1843 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01843: not a
>   valid month` (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ipack\insertstatus.php:60 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ipack\insertstatus.php(60): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\ipack\insertstatus.php on line 60

This is my code:

```
$today = date("d-m-Y");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO PRTJOBSTATUS (INTJOBNO,SLNO,OPDATE,OPERTYPE,OPUSER,REMARKS,STATUSCODE,STATDATE) 
    values (:intjn,:sn,:opdt,:optype,:opusr,:rmks,:stcd,:stdt)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':intjn',$intjobno);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sn',$slno);
    $stmt->bindParam(':opdt',$today);
    $stmt->bindParam(':optype',$optype);
    $stmt->bindParam(':opusr',$opuser);
    $stmt->bindParam(':rmks',$remarks);
    $stmt->bindParam(':stcd',$statuscode);
    $stmt->bindParam(':stdt',$today);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
      echo '1 row has been inserted';  
    }
    $dbh = null;
```

Comment: this is not the relevant code, there is no line 60

Comment: Not an expert in php but can figure it out error is coming because one of the input date column is having invalid month. You can try it out with default date format i.e. DD-MON-RR

Comment: Error is on $stmt->execute statement

Comment: i changed date format to date('d-M-y'), now its working fine. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting into a column "STATDATE". I would imagine this will be of type Date. Therefore you'll have to pass a date object into the insert statement.

Change your $today variable to return a string in the following format 'DD-MON-YYYY' eg 31-DEC-2015
Then change your insert statement to the following:

```
"INSERT INTO PRTJOBSTATUS (INTJOBNO,SLNO,OPDATE,OPERTYPE,OPUSER,REMARKS,STATUSCODE,STATDATE) 
values (:intjn,:sn,:opdt,:optype,:opusr,:rmks,:stcd,TO_DATE(:stdt,'DD-MON-YYYY'))"
```

Comment: Exactly @Fudztown. i changed date format to date('d-M-y'), now its working fine. thanks a lot.